# AX2009 progressive character count dialog filed

Tags: forms, axapta

I need to do an active progress character count on a dialog field. I will be using this dialog as a user input for sending an SMS from AX (no problems with that bit of the code).
So SMS is limited by 160 characters, and I need to display the character count as the user types: 160 - current count = characters left.

Comment: Please show your code or any attempts you have made. Ask specific questions with code examples and you will get a lot more help

Comment: Sorry yes I would have done so, how ever I was struggling to even get down some basic code as I did not know where to start really, how ever I have been advised to consider using a From Class object rather than my initial thoughts of a Dialog Box... Once I have this sorted and working I will return to this thread and post the code for comments, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dialog is a form and not generated for example with the `Dialog` class Framework, you could [overwrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa607131.aspx) the `textChange` method on your input control. In this method you can retrieve the text entered so far and determine the number of characters in the text. With this information you can you can display the remaining characters for example on another static text control in your dialog form.

Comment: Many thanks for you guidance, my initial thoughts were along a Dialog Box, how ever I will now seriously look at the Form Class objects...